# Isomorphisms in category theory

Tags: category-theory

I'm having trouble understanding isomorphisms.

E.g. in the category **Posets** which Awodey defines to be the category with posets as objects and monotone functions as arrows, he explains that bijective homomorphisms are not necessarily isomorphisms. His example are the Posets $A=(U,≤_A)$ and $B=(U,≤_B)$ with $U=\{0,1\}$ and $≤_A=\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$ and $≤_B=\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,1)\}$.

Now there is obviously an Arrow $f:A→B$ corresponding to the identity on U and the identity on U is also an arrow $g:B→A$. What I don't understand is: ***why are they not inverse?***

Of course it seems to be like this because B is totally ordered while A is not, but I don't see how I can prove that. If I define arrows to be monotone functions they operate on Elements in U and for those $f\circ g$ is the identity.

Comment: Note that isomorphisms of posets are bijective maps $f : P \to Q$ which satisfy $p \leq p'$ if and only if $f(p) \leq f(p')$. (Similarly, isomorphisms of topological spaces are bijective maps $f:X \to Y$ such that $U \subseteq Y$ is open if and only if $f^{-1}(U)$ is open.)

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have $0\le_B 1$, but $g(0)\not\le_A g(1)$. So $g$ is not an arrow in $\mathbf{Poset}$.

More generally, $(U,\le_A)$ is *totally disordered*, so any map $U\to V$ ($V$ with any order relation) is monotone, because there's no pair that can falsify it.

It's quite easy to see that if $A=(U,\le_A)$ and $B=(V,\le_B)$ are isomorphic in $\mathbf{Poset}$ and $A$ is totally disordered, then also $B$ is. With a similar technique, if $A$ is totally ordered, then any poset isomorphic to $A$ is again totally ordered.

As Martin Brandenburg observes, $f\colon A\to B$ is an isomorphism if and only if

- $f$ is bijective and
- $x\le_A y$ if and only if $f(x)\le_B f(y)$.

Comment: How did I not see that? Thx!